# Remove previous onOptionsItemSelected between fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a toolbar with some actions, but those actions should change when I change the fragment to another. 
I put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the `onCreate` of each fragment that I need to change the action of the toolbar item. 
Example fragment 1 `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.borrarlote:
            Toast.makeText(viewRoot.getContext(), "Parametros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Only have to show me a Toast with the name of the fragments, it does correctly. 
Now I change to fragment 2, I repeat the `setHasOptions(true)` in the `onCreate` and the `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.borrarlote:
            Toast.makeText(viewRoot.getContext(), "Fragment Inicio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

In my theory the app will shows a Toast saying "Fragment Inicio" but in the reality it shows a Toast saying "Parametros" and then another saying "Fragment Inicio". 
It's like the options doesn´t change, just add the new action to the list of actions you have to do each time you click on that item. 
Is there any way to clean the actions when I enter a new fragment?

Greetings

Comment: Can you share your code of fragment transaction?

Comment: @Md.Didarulislam getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contenedor, fragment).addToBackStack("Some String").commit();

Comment: Have you tried by not adding previous fragment to BackStack ?

Comment: Tried right now, nothings happens, two toast in a row @Md.Didarulislam

Answer (score 0):

I solve it creating a menu.xml for each fragment that I need and inflating the menu on it. Works perfectly